# How to save an Image to Clients System using .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an Image I am retrieving from the database as a byte array. I want to save it outside the Project i.e on the Clients System. I would appreciate if the code aspect can be assisted with. Here is a sample method I have so far:

```cs
public Image byteArrayToImage2()
{
    var filePath = "C:\\cat.jpg";           
  
    byte[] fileBytes =  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    Image returnImage = null;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
    {
        returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

        returnImage.Save("cat2.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    }

    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: You should look at how to download a file. You cannot write directly on the client machine, you let the user download the image and save it wherever they like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below approach

PS: make sure your fileBytes is of type byte Array.

```
MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
imageStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);                                                                             

// Include the file name along with extension (Eg: 'C:\TestImage.JPEG')
FileStream fs = File.Create("Give the path where you want to save the image");
imageStream.WriteTo(fs);

fs.Close();
imageStream.Close();
```

Comment: The question implies asp.net core thus webserver and such it is not likely that the OP actually has access to write directly to the the client machine.